# How to test CSRF Attack in Asp.Net Web Application?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, csrf

Hi I'm new to Security of Web Applications.

I want to test my application for the same purpose.

I have a form, which has some fields and a submit button.

So User X is logged in and he submits the form and now I want to know how hackers can attack on my Application.

I have read I need to post the html code of my aspx page. But I dont know how can I post the form with incorrect data filled in form with html. So is there any tool to test this ? 
or If with html of my page how can I test it?

Comment: Check this [Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Security with Haack and Hanselman](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/FT05)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If it's ASP.NET MVC application.I suggest you to use AntitForgeryToken.If it's not ASP.NET MVC then 
Save Session Id in View State then viewstate will be acting like form token .Protect sessionid by using some encryption or signing mechanism and use SSL to prevent sniffing. Finally you just need to verify your sessionid and ViewState

Comment: 'the html code of my aspx page' sounds not like ASP.NET MVC. And it's not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool i have found is this: https://portswigger.net/burp/

It has a feature where you can intercept the request and generate a CSRF. The details on this feature can be found here: https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1965674-using-burp-to-test-for-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking how to test cross site anti-forgery rather than actually defend against it. There is plenty on the web about defending against it (http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/) as an example.

An example of how to test if you are currently defending against this is to log into your website, then open up another tab containing html with a form to post to that website. As your session is maintained by the browser that website will authorize the post request if you haven't put in any defense mechanisms.

Below is a sample of how you would go about doing this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www/w3/org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="document.getElementById('attacker').submit()">
     <form id="attacker" action="https://website-in-question.com/Action" method="post">
        <input name="FirstName" value="SomeFirstName" />
        <input name="LastName" value="SomeLastName" />
        <input name="EmailAddress" value="SomeFirstName.SomeLastName@Hack.com" />
    </form>
    <p>CROSS SITE REQUEST FORGERY IN PROGRESS....</p>
</body>
```

The JavaScript within this page is included to demonstrate how an end user would may not even be aware that any data was being posted on their behalf, as the form could be hidden.

You would need to replace the contents of the action attribute with the URL of your POST method.

Comment: I'm inheriting this page from master page, so I don't have form tag. so in this case where should I use action attribute and method post? This page has Content tag instead of form tag.

Comment: CSRF only occurs when you have a page exposed that allows the HTTP POST method to post data (which may be entered into a database or can somehow manipulate state on your server). If you are simply posting the contents of your page back to the server then the action would be the URL of your page. It's hard to know without knowing which technologies you are using.

Comment: I'm using asp.net 4.0.

Comment: So how ever you are posting the data on your current page which you want to test, replicate that behavior in the same way as the example above (by replacing the form with whatever you have), log in to your website to ensure you have a session token on your machine, and then POST the data through using the page you have created locally on your machine. CSRF attacks happen because your session is persisted on the server and when the browser posts a form or any data it posts it from the client. therefor the server verifies you are logged in and authenticates the call allowing the post.